# Load Data Infile + Disable/Enable Keys Performance

Tags: sql, mysql, load-data-infile

I have a table with approximately 7 million rows.  Once a day, I need to bulk import around 200,000 new rows into this table.  To do this, I am first disabling keys on the table, using `LOAD DATA INFILE`, and then re-enabling keys on the table.

The problem I am having is with the `ALTER TABLE my_table ENABLE KEYS` statement.
It takes around 15 minutes to complete.  I am trying to improve the performance by increasing `myisam_sort_buffer_size`, but it doesn't seem to help.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can try external MySQL tools like mysqladmin and myisamchk. They are in /usr/local/mysql/bin path for a regular installation.

A solution path from the MySQL Web Site:

> - Execute a FLUSH TABLES statement or a mysqladmin flush-tables command.
> - Use myisamchk --keys-used=0 -rq /path/to/db/tbl_name. This removes all
>     use of indexes for the table.
> - Insert data into the table with LOAD DATA INFILE. This does not update any
>     indexes and therefore is very fast.
> - If you intend only to read from the table in the future, use myisampack to
>     compress it. See Section 13.4.3.3,
>     “Compressed Table Characteristics”.
> - Re-create the indexes with myisamchk -rq /path/to/db/tbl_name. This creates the index tree in memory before
>     writing it to disk, which is much
>     faster that updating the index during
>     LOAD DATA INFILE because it avoids
>     lots of disk seeks. The resulting
>     index tree is also perfectly balanced.
> - Execute a FLUSH TABLES statement or a mysqladmin flush-tables command.

[mysql official documents](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-speed.html)

Comment: if cardinality Value is not updated for your your table's indexes myisamchk -rqa /path/to/db/tbl_name options will work properly

Comment: Also note that using `ALTER TABLE <table> DISABLE KEYS` (and `... ENABLE KEYS`) is the same as using the `myisamchk` commands (I was a bit confused if there was a difference, then read rest of MySQL docs)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to minimize downtime caused by your table being locked, I believe that standard procedure is to clone the table, perform the insertion in the clone (with or without disabling keys, depending on your specific circumstances) and once done, issue a `DROP TABLE tableName;RENAME TABLE tableClone TO tableName`